# Bash printf confusion

Tags: bash, printf

I have been having a hard time figuring out how a specific line of bash script works.  If anyone could break down how exactly this printf statement works it would be greatly appreciated.

```
printf "%${SPACES}s{FNAME}\n" " "
```

Where SPACES is a number and FNAME is the basename of a file or directory.  More detail the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `SPACE=5` then `printf` is equivalent to:

```
printf "%5s{FNAME}\n" " "
```

Which gives this output:

```
     {FNAME}
12345
```

i.e. 5 spaces and literal string `{FNAME}`

Any number between `%` and `s` is being used for `space padding` before actual string.

Comment: Im still confused on the purpose of %10 and the s before {FNAME}

Comment: Yes I have added explanation in my answer.